# How to remove array items between specific values that contains specific phrase

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using Javascript. I have an array where I want to filter out all the array values which are between certain values that contain a specific phrase. Here is an example array:

```
   var array = [
      '[en]: The sun rises at 6:00',
      '[en]: Its time for brakefast',
      '[en]: comment_start',
      '[en]: Lorun ipsum a dummy text',
      '[en]: Mauris consequat massa ante',
      '[en]: In hac habitasse platea dictumst',
      '[en]: comment_end',
      '[en]: The sun sets at 6:30'
    ]
```

As per the above example javascript array, how can I remove all the **array values between** values that contain phrase "*comment_start*" and "*comment_end*"?

Currently, I am not using any 3rd party library to like Loadash to handle arrays and objects.

Comment: Your array can/may contain multiple `comment_start` and `comment_end`?

Comment: first you can get the index where to start deleting and index where to stop deleting and then use splice to delete

Comment: No array can not contain multiple phrase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try something like this, we'll start filtering once we hit a comment section, then stop once we exit.

You could also use array.reduce in a similar manner.

```js
  var array = [
   '[en]: The sun rises at 6:00',
   '[en]: Its time for brakefast',
   '[en]: comment_start',
   '[en]: Lorun ipsum a dummy text',
   '[en]: Mauris consequat massa ante',
   '[en]: In hac habitasse platea dictumst',
   '[en]: comment_end',
   '[en]: The sun sets at 6:30'
 ];
  
  var inCommentSection = false;
  var result = array.filter(v => {
 if (!inCommentSection) {
  inCommentSection = v.includes("comment_start");
 } else {
  inCommentSection = !v.includes("comment_end");
  return false;
 }
 return !inCommentSection;
  });
  
  
 console.log("Result", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using .indexOf() and .slice().
Edit as per comment to not use '[en]...'

```
var array = [
      '[en]: The sun rises at 6:00',
      '[en]: Its time for brakefast',
      '[en]: comment_start',
      '[en]: Lorun ipsum a dummy text',
      '[en]: Mauris consequat massa ante',
      '[en]: In hac habitasse platea dictumst',
      '[en]: comment_end',
      '[en]: The sun sets at 6:30'
    ]
const start = array.indexOf(array.find(element => {
                return element.match('comment_start')
              })
            )
const end = array.indexOf(array.find(element => {
                return element.match('comment_end')
              })
            )
const middleComments = array.slice(start + 1, end)

return middleComments
```

Comment: Yup close but actually, I don't want to consider `[en]` here. Rather I want to search for the phrase in values. Check the selected answer, its exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer to fulfill your requirements. It is still a valid solution so I will keep it up for others to reference

Comment: yeah. This works. Thanks for sharing. Also please check answer from Terry which is much more cleaner and leaner way.